# when calling the UpdateMethod operation getting invalid path error for /methodIntegration/uri

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm updating an API in AWS API Gateway. This is my lambda function:

```
response = client.update_method(
                    restApiId=rest_api_id,
                    resourceId=resource_id,
                    httpMethod= "GET", #method
                    patchOperations=[
                        {
                            'op': 'replace',
                            # 'path': '/apiKeyRequired',
                            # 'value': 'true',
                            'path': '/methodIntegration/uri',
                            'value': 'https://stackoverflow.com',
                        },
                    ]
                )
```

This works fine and updates "API key required" field, but when I try to update the "URI" field it throws the following error.
`"errorMessage": "An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the UpdateMethod operation: Invalid patch path /methodIntegration/uri",`

The path looks fine to me. Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-method.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apiKeyRequired` works because it is a [valid property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/method/#apiKeyRequired) of a `method`. To update `integration` you should use [update-integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-integration.html) where `uri` is its [valid property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/).